# Not getting fieldset as a option while adding new fields in content type

Tags: 7

I am adding new field in content type and I want that field's Field type to be Fieldset but there is no such option in Field type column.

Can anyone know how can I add new field's Field type as Fieldset

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no 'fieldset' field type as such.

If you want to wrap entity fields in fieldsets, install the [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module:

> Fieldgroup will, as the name implies, group fields together. All fieldable entities will have the possibility to add groups to wrap their fields together. Fieldgroup comes with default HTML wrappers like vertical tabs, horizontal tabs, accordions, fieldsets or div wrappers.

Comment: I have already installed Field Group module.Which option i need to select while adding field group as fieldset in adding content type?

Comment: At the bottom of the manage fields form you'll see **Add new group**; fill in a name for the group, choose a type, add it, then once it's added you'll be able to drag 'proper' fields underneath it. When you view the form, the changes you've made will show up